# Scanning 3D model outside surface and creating model copy using Autodesk forge API

Tags: javascript, java, autodesk-forge, bim

I am researching a way to select (or scan) the surface of an existing 3D model of a building and using selected data to create a new model. For this I am using Java, JS and Autodesk Forge API. What I am trying to achieve is a copy of a model that should contain only surface walls, roof and balcony. The original model would consist of full BIM model containing, for example, staircases, walls separating rooms, furniture and so on. I tried searching for methods to use for my research, but sadly failed, so my questions regarding this would be:

- whether it is possible using Autodesk Forge API to create a copy of a model in a new file using selected elements as a base
- if there are any approaches to select elements that can be seen from outside, but ain't inside.

I would appreciate any suggestions regarding this as I am wondering if forge actually has any methods regarding this and if any extra library should be applied in order to achieve my goal.

Comment: About the your 1st question, Forge MD has a feature called `Geometry Extraction`, you can take a look here: https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/extract-geometry-from-source-file/

Comment: But I'm not pretty sure what you want to do regarding your 2nd question. Did you want to Viewer to select the wall surface exposed to outside of a building for example?

Comment: @EasonKang Thank you for the answer to the first question. As for the second question - yes, I would like to select walls exposed to the outside.

Comment: If you want to select partial surface mesh of exterior walls, I have to say sorry that it's not possible as I know. The select function of the Viewer will highlight all meshes belongs to a 3D element e.g. a wall.

Comment: If you just want to select all exterior walls of a building, so called the walls in the building envelop, I would advise you to calculate it in the BIM software directly (e.g. Revit API's BuildingEnvelopeAnalyzer )  or export your models into gbXML format, since it requires complex mesh calculation, it might make your browser crash. http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/01/family-category-and-two-energy-model-types.html